# Opening a COM Port using a Windows Compact 2013 Virtual PC

Tags: windows, com, embedded, windows-ce

```
HANDLE hCom = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

hCom = CreateFileW(
    L"COM1:",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);
```

I am trying to open a COM Port of my Computer with a virtual pc (Windows Embedded Compact). 
The function CreateFileW delivers an INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. On win32 it works perfect.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Check the value returned by the `GetLastError()` function. This will most likely give you a hint why the com port could not be opened.

Comment: Are ports named the same under WinCE?  I expect that there aren't any DosDevices aliases.

Answer (score 3):

Check the port names under HKLM\Drivers\Active.
You can use remote registry editor to do this.
You'll find a list of keys with numerical names but, inside each subkey, you can find devices names like COM1: (that is a valid device name on CE).
Usually BSPs use a serial port for debug output, this will prevent the OS from using it. You may need to disable serial debug output by passing the right parameter to your bootloader (LOADCEPC has a command line switch, biosloader can be configured using an .ini file), allowing the system to access that port as a regular serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GetLastError()` to check error code.

For opening gps com port I have this code (it works both on range of wince versions and on desktop windows too):

```
if ( port > 9 )      
  sport.Format(_T("\\\\.\\COM%d"), port);
else
  sport.Format(_T("COM%d:"), port);

HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(sport.GetString(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```